# Identifying Visual Studio Branches

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm working on a project where I need to have a few branches of the same source code open at the same time.  Is there an easy way to tell at-a-glance what branch I'm looking at on visual studio.  At the moment I'm inspecting the properties of a source file to view the path in order to identify the branch.

There must be a better way - how can I tell at a glance what branch I'm looking at?

Comment: are you talking about git? VS team system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [VsCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features) extension. It shows the current branch in the solution badge in the taskbar, and the title bar. I am using mercurial and it seems to work well with that.

Comment: This seems to have the feature I need, but it only tells me 'branch' in the badge and not 'which branch'

Comment: It looks like it has integration with a few version control systems, failing that it parses it out from the dir path. The regex for that can be changed in the [options](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features#solutionbadge)

Comment: @reach4thelasers, Hi, I'm the author of VSCommands, it should work out of the box by default as Vdex said. Which source control software do you use? Most lacking at the moment is TFS integration, but I have private build ready with it improved so if you need just let me know at Jarek@squaredinfinity.com

Comment: TFS :) yeah I will email you to get the build

Answer (score 0):

Use the free Branch Info TE Extension (BITE) for VS2013:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/33a5274b-271b-45dd-8dc5-734d927a19dd?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score -1):

If it's exactly the same code - what's the point in it?
If it's not, maybe use different named projects inside the same solution?

BTW, you don't have to change default namespace with the project name, so it should be relatively easy to do.

Then there's another way - hover your mouse pointer over the file tab, you'll see the file path almost immediately. I do that every time I work on new version, but checking something from the old version.

If there are only 2 versions - you can use 2 monitors. I put the old (less used) version on "side" display, and current (most changed) on "front" one.

Comment: If you don't understand the need for branches then you shouldn't be answering questions on here.

Comment: You're right. Though I rather didn't understand the need to open more branches at the same time and VS instance. I'm sorry, I still have a lot to learn.